# Mysql getting shutdown /restart frequently

Tags: mysql, database-connection, mysql-5.7

The MySQL server is shutting down and restarting frequently. multiple time with in a day
Please check the details log here from .err error log

I am unable to under stand why the issue is coming my application is designed on .net at front-end end and mysql 5.7 in back-end

Below is the error which i am getting in my .err file

```
2020-03-11T12:51:45.948716Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2020-03-11T12:51:45.948716Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2020-03-11T12:51:45.948716Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-03-11T12:51:45.948716Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-03-11T12:51:45.948716Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-03-11T12:51:46.011201Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 2 events
2020-03-11T12:51:46.011201Z 1 [Note] Event Scheduler: scheduler thread started with id 1
2020-03-11T12:51:46.011201Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.18-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-03-11T12:51:46.011201Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check. 
2020-03-11T12:51:46.011201Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2020-03-11T12:51:49.744699Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2020-03-11T12:51:50.729096Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200311 18:21:50
2020-03-11T12:55:43.222327Z 124 [Note] Aborted connection 124 to db: 'newtnt' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-03-11T12:55:43.222327Z 126 [Note] Aborted connection 126 to db: 'newtnt' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-03-11T12:55:43.222327Z 125 [Note] Aborted connection 125 to db: 'newtnt' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-03-11T12:55:43.222327Z 127 [Note] Aborted connection 127 to db: 'newtnt' user: 'root' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2020-03-12T10:37:09.937553Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

2020-03-12T10:37:09.941542Z 0 [Note] Giving 2 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2020-03-12T10:37:09.942540Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2020-03-12T10:37:11.956150Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 2 remaining clients
2020-03-12T10:37:11.956150Z 0 [Warning] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: Forcing close of thread 39557  user: 'root'

2020-03-12T10:37:11.957149Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Killing the scheduler thread, thread id 1
2020-03-12T10:37:11.957149Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Waiting for the scheduler thread to reply
2020-03-12T10:37:11.958145Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Stopped
2020-03-12T10:37:11.959142Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 2 events
2020-03-12T10:37:11.959142Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-03-12T10:37:12.010479Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.018963Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.018963Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'FEDERATED'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.018963Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.019965Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.019965Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.022865Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.022865Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.022865Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.023868Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.023868Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.024863Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.024863Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.025860Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.025860Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.025860Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.026858Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.026858Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.027855Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.027855Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.027855Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.028852Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.028852Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.029850Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.029850Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.029850Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.030847Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.030847Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.031845Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.031845Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.032842Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.032842Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.032842Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.033839Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.033839Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.034836Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.034836Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.034836Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.035834Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2020-03-12T10:37:12.035834Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2020-03-12T10:37:12.036858Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2020-03-12T10:37:12.138960Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-03-12T10:37:12.146935Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 200312 16:07:12
2020-03-12T10:37:14.244479Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 95582662
2020-03-12T10:37:14.245474Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-03-12T10:37:14.245474Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2020-03-12T10:37:14.245474Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-03-12T10:37:14.246472Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2020-03-12T10:37:14.246472Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2020-03-12T10:37:14.247469Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2020-03-12T10:37:14.276249Z 0 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The dba sister site of SO offers more help in database admin type of questions.

Comment: Check access_log of your server